# How to make citation for a new paper in arxiv?

Tags: publications, citations, computer-science, arxiv

I have uploaded a preprint to the arXiv. I can find it in google search now. However, I cannot find it in google scholar. The reason for searching in Google scholar is that I want to make a BibTeX citation for my paper as below. Do I need to do something for my paper to appear in Google Scholar or do I just have to wait?

```
@article{tatarchenko2017octree,
  title={Octree Generating Networks: Efficient Convolutional Architectures for High-resolution 3D Outputs},
  author={Tatarchenko, Maxim and Dosovitskiy, Alexey and Brox, Thomas},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1703.09438},
  year={2017}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Can you please [edit] your question to specify what you want to achieve and what the problem is? I fail to see what Google Scholar has to do with you citing something with BibTeX.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I believe that the connection is that Google Scholar has a BibTeX export functionality.

Comment: If you only want to have a BibTeX export - this is possible on the arXiv website itself via NASA ADS.

Comment: You could always write the citation yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Christian mentions, there are already BibTex entries for your articles.

On NASA ADS: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=2017arXiv170309438T&data_type=BIBTEX&db_key=PRE&nocookieset=1

On the University of Trier database: http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/journals/corr/TatarchenkoDB17

Whether you use one of these or wait for the one from Google Scholar, the main issue will be how your bibtex style renders the citation. You may need to adjust the fields "journal", "pages" and/or "eprint" to obtain a suitable result.

EDIT: I found those links on the arxiv page https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.09438 on the right column, as mentioned by ff524

Comment: It's probably worth noting that you can get these links from the arXiv page, in the sidebar on the right side.

Comment: Yes. I must wait for the google scholar. It is automatic generating it